# Why nested enums are implicitly static in java?

Tags: java, enums

What's the reason of making them such? For example, I may want to have an inner enum that will be used as a property of enclosing class and then depending on that property value return one of two distinct properties of enclosing class that implement the same interface, like here

```
class Moo{
enum Blah {
Hey{
Awwable awwableMe() {
return Moo.this.oe1;}
}, Ho{
Awwable awwableMe() {
return Moo.this.oe2;}
};
abstract Awwable awwableMe();
}

private Awwable oe1;

private Awwable oe2;

private Blah smth;

void Awwable theSomeMethod() {
return smth.awwableMe(); //or any other code that uses smth.awwableMe();
}
}
```

But I can't write such code as I can't reference `Moo.this.oe1` or `oe2` as they're in non static context and in enum I'm in it.

Comment: What? Please format your code and try to explain with some sample code.

Comment: Why is a rather difficult question to answer. Because the specs say so. Why do they say so? I'd guess cause the specwriters thought it'd cause more trouble than happiness if object1's Hey was different from object2's Hey.

Comment: Partly, enums are an afterthought in Java, and something of a compiler fiction, so you get what you get.  But enums don't really "fit" any language very well (Pascal probably has the best "fit", and it's good but not great), so there's always an irregular feeling about them.

Comment: In a pinch, you could have your `enum` have a method `abstract Awwable awwable(Moo moo)`.

Comment: (And, of course, according to the JLS nothing is "implicitly static".  It's only static if tagged `static`.  But the JLS doesn't believe in ducks.)

Answer (score 2):

It will not make any sense if you make an instance-level (non-static) inner enum class - if the instances of the enum were tied to the outer class they will break the enum guarantee

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.9):

> **Discussion**
>
> Instance methods declared in these class bodies are may be invoked
>   outside the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible
>   methods in the enclosing enum type.
>
> Enum types (§8.9) must not be declared abstract; doing so will result
>   in a compile-time error. It is a compile-time error for an enum type E
>   to have an abstract method m as a member unless E has one or more enum
>   constants, and all of E's enum constants have class bodies that
>   provide concrete implementations of m. It is a compile-time error for
>   the class body of an enum constant to declare an abstract method.
>
> An enum type is implicitly final unless it contains at least one enum
>   constant that has a class body. In any case, it is a compile-time
>   error to explicitly declare an enum type to be final.
>
> **Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissable to
>   explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.**

Also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum
>   constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly
>   instantiate an enum type (§15.9.1).

Comment: This is probably only true within a single classloader.